# Testing for any of a family of related values in a Bash variable

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

Apologies if this has been answered previously, but I couldn't find much online.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
if [[ "${hostname}" = (foo | bar)servername(01 | 02 | 03) ]]; then
  var="foobarfoo"
fi
```

With this any of the following would meet the criteria: fooservername01, barservername02, fooservername03, barservername03, etc.

I've accomplished this in a much more inefficient fashion:

```
if [[ ${hostname} == "fooservername01" ]] || [[ ${hostname} == "fooservername02" ]] || [[ ${hostname} == "fooservername03" ]] || [[ ${hostname} == "barservername01" ]] || [[ ${hostname} == "barservername02" ]] || [[ ${hostname} == "barservername03" ]]; then
  var="foobarfoo"
fi
```

But I am looking to optimize/streamline the code.

Any insight would be appreciated as I'm still very new to bash scripting and even scripting in general.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34762241/1030675

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this very nearly exactly as you've written it. When you're using [`[[` then `==`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_005b_005b) uses [pattern-matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) on the right-hand side. In a Bash pattern, you can match one of a selection of patterns using `@(a|b|c)`:

```
if [[ "${hostname}" = @(foo|bar)servername@(01|02|03) ]]; then
```

That matches each of the cases you identify. `@( ... | ... )` matches any one of the `|`-separated patterns inside it. You [can also](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) use other globs `*` and `?`, `[character classes]`, and further composite patterns for repeated, optional, or negated patterns.

Using these extended patterns needs the `extglob` shell option enabled. If it's not on already (you'll get a syntax error), you can enable it with:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

anywhere before your `if` appears.

---

If you prefer and you're more familiar with them, you can also use arbitrary [extended regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) by using the `=~` operator in place of `==`.

Comment: This is very close to what I had, but your suggestion doesn't actually appear to be working. I'm not getting a syntax error or anything, but the condition is not being met, even when I know it should be. Here's what I'm currently testing:

    if [[ "${shortHostname}" == "@(euslc|eulvs)prdapp@(05|22|23)" ]]; then
  store="trufr"
else
  store="WRONG"
    fi

The shortHostname var is currently set to eulvsprdapp05, but it's setting the store var to WRONG.

Comment: Don't quote the pattern on the right-hand side - then it's just treated as a string, for string equality.

Comment: Now I get a syntax error:

foo: line 3: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `('
foo: line 3: syntax error near `@(e'
foo: line 3: `if [[ "${shortHostname}" == @(euslc|eulvs)prdapp@(05|22|23) ]]; then'

Comment: What bash version?

Comment: This system (and the others in the infrastructure) are all: 

bash-3.2-33.el5_11.4

And this will most likely not be changed.

Comment: You do need `extglob` enabled for the `@+*!?` patterns to work - `shopt -s extglob` will turn it on. It's not on by default in 3.2.

Comment: @Tronyx Put that into the script, somewhere near the top (or at least above your `if`).

Comment: That did the trick!  Thanks so much for all of your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

```
case ${hostname%"servername0"[123]} in
("$hostname") ! :;; 
(foo|bar) ;;
(*) ! :;; esac
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `grep` for that. For example:

```bash
HOST_REGEX='(foo|bar)servername(01|02|03)'

if grep -qE "${HOST_REGEX}" <<< "${hostname}"
then
  var="foobarfoo"
fi
```

On one line:

```bash
grep -qE '(foo|bar)servername(01|02|03)' <<< "${hostname}" && var="foobarfoo"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `=~` test operator. This accepts (unquoted) Extended Regular Expressions (similar to `egrep`).

```
if [[ "$hostname" =~ (foo|bar)servername(01|02|03) ]]
then echo matches
else echo no match
fi
```